# Threads are blocked due to unable to close database connection

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

In the stacktrace, `MessageProcessor.Dispose()`, `OnThreadShutdownRequested` and `RenewTaskLeaseCallback` all require a lock to prevent race conditions in these objects.
The stacktrace for thread (ID14968) holds all the locks, which causes the other threads to block and wait for it to release the locks.

The problem is that, when `CloseConnection()` is called on thread-14968, the connection is never closed, and `SyncAsyncLock.Wait()` was called internally inside `CloseConnection()`. Call is blocked and would not continue, and a deadlock situation occurs.

What would possibly cause the thread to block when `CloseConnection()` was called?

Larger image [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5LqE9IVzH2wU05VOHZSeTBaZnM/edit?usp=sharing).
[image: stacktrace of the deadlocked threads]

Comment: The image link is not accessible due to permissions.

Comment: sorry, my permission setting was wrong, it's now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this issue for two days, I finally figured out the problem.
There was a situation that could result a deadlock in the application.

The `TaskLeaseRenewer` object implements `IDisposable` and can be accessed by multiple threads. A lock is used inside the class to make sure no two threads will try to dispose the object at the same time. `TaskLeaseRenewer` has a timer, and  callback function `Callback` that will be called periodically by the timer, on a separate thread. The `Callback` thread will try to call `Thread.Abort()` on the thread that created the `TaskLeaseRenewer` and eventually call `Dispose()` on `TaskLeaseRenwer`

The problem happens when I try to abort the thread that does does the following:

```
using(TaskLeaseRenewer renewer = new TaskLeaseRewnewer())
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

I found out that when you call `Thread.Abort()` on a thread with `using` statements, it will not terminate the thread until it call the `Dispose()` function on the used object.

The example below will trigger `ConnectionWrapper.Dispose()` before the thread is aborted.

```
static void DisposeOnAbort()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using connection wrapper");
        using (ConnectionWrapper wrapper = new ConnectionWrapper())
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    });
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Aborting thread..");
    t.Abort();
}
```

Given these, I found the problem is when `Callback()` calls `Thread.Abort()`, `TaskLeaseRenewer.Dispose()` will be called on the thread it was created because the thread is getting ready to be killed. However `Callback()` function is on a different thread and also holding the lock the `Dispose()` function is trying to acquire. `Dispose()` will not be able to acquire the lock, and the thread will never terminate.

After solving this problem, the `connection.Close()` deadlock seems to be gone. I am still interested in what could be blocking the connection from closing.

After playing around with this problem more, i find when a thread is aborted, the disposable object's `Dispose()` object is always called. whether `using` statement is used or not. Callstack as follows:

```
Threads.exe!Threads.ConnectionWrapper.Dispose() Line 150    C#
Threads.exe!Threads.Program.DisposeOnAbort.AnonymousMethod__0() Line 58 + 0x2c bytes    C#
```